# Prefixing a URL in an window.open function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, execution, prefix, multiple-instances

I have this HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('TrackPackage.asp?ID=4', '', 'settings');">Track Your Package »</a>
```

Somebody on this site was able to provide me with a script to prefix the URL with the domain `http://www.example.com/` Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[onclick^="window.open(\'TrackPackage.asp"]').attr('onClick', $('a[onclick^="window.open(\'TrackPackage.asp"]').attr('onClick').replace("window.open('", "window.open('http://www.example.com/"));
});
```

However, I am having a little trouble with this:
The first issue is where there is multiple instances of the element. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VMmZx/
Instead of one anchor being signed with `ID=4` and the other with `ID=5` as intended, they're both being signed with `ID=4`. 
*The idea is, each `window.open` function should be prefixed with `http://www.example.com` however, the remainder of the URL should remain intact...*

The second problem I'm encountering is when the element does not exist on a page, the remainder of the jQuery fails... 
Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPf32/
The `<a>` should get the class `foo`, but since the element does not exist on the page, the jQuery does not execute.
*Since the JavaScript is being included in the HTML template of the ASP.NET server, this can create many problems.*

I hope I've been clear and you can help me. **Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing the click even inline like that? I would just output the links like:

```
<a href="/path/to/file.html" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

And then:

```
$('a[target=_blank]').click(function(){
   var prefix = 'http://domain.com';
   window.open(prefix + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: HTML isn't under my control, unfortunately. I've heard the same thing numerous times and would've done this a long time ago...

Comment: Ahh the annoyances of only having purview over the frontend.

Comment: Yesss... it kills me. Maybe one day, I'll be able to write my own software ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to iterate over each matching element and change them individually:

```
$('a[onclick^="window.open(\'TrackPackage.asp"]').each(function(index, element) {
    element = $(element);
    element.attr('onclick', element.attr('onclick').replace(/open\('/, 'open(\'http://www.example.com/'));
});​
```

However, I don't think using links with a `href` of `#` and an `onclick` opening a window is as semantic as it could be. If possible, try changing the markup to this:

```
<a href="TrackPackage.asp?ID=4" target="_blank">Track Your Package »</a>
```

Now if someone is curious where it will lead them, the browser can show something useful in the status bar when you hover over it.

If you need to adjust the behavior further, add a class and bind for the `click` event. When they click, prevent the default action and open the window yourself, as you did before.

Comment: This is actually making other problems for me... it cannot evaluate an undefined function. The original jQuery works... I'll need another script.

Comment: HTML isn't under my control, unfortunately. I've heard the same thing numerous times and would've done this a long time ago...